# Design a bank account and membership UML diagram (OO design)

Tags: oop, uml, system-design

I'm designing a back account membership system with UML diagram.

My idea is that create a class `userAccount` and 2 subclasses `savingAccount` and `currentAccount` that inherits `userAccounts`

With membership, I have created a membership interface `Membership` and 3 classes implemented, `Gold`, `Silver`, `Bronze`.

So I wanted different membership to have different withdraw limit and transfer limit for both accounts, but only the `interestRateCalculation()` will be applied into the `savingAccount` class.

I have implemented the UML diagram like the way in the picture.[image: the UML Diagram]

However, I feel like this is not the right way of implementing this. Since the accounts didn't inherit the `membership` classes, so the methods in the accounts classes shouldn't be able to retrieve those methods in the `membership` classes. But if not implemented with this way, I cannot find a better way to implement it.

I would like to know what is the more accurate way to implement the diagram. Much appreciated.

Comment: I can imagine what a `Saving`(s) account is, but what is a `Current` account?? Currency perhaps? Also: as per common convention let you class names start with a capital letter.

Comment: Ha, It's a typo, thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I see in the membership classes seems independent of any account, if this is true :

- There are only 1 instance of each sub class in all the system, so a total of 3 and each is a singleton.
- The fact *IMembership* aggregates *userAccount* has no sense, it does not have to know the accounts
- Probably an account is associated to one and only one of the three singleton, allowing an account to know the limits and how to compute the interest. In that case you have a directional association from *userAccount* to *IMembership*

It is abnormal the attributes *withdrawLimit* and *transfertLimit* are present in the four membership classes, they must be present only in *IMembership* whose must be an abstract class rather than an interface

For me *userAccount* must be an abstract class because you cannot have an account whose is not one of the two sub classes.

The operations *getWithdrawLimit* and *getTransfertLimit* only depend on the membership so they are defined on *userAccount* rather than on the sub classes, of course these operation call the corresponding one on the associated membership instance.

[image]

(I do not defined the constructor to save time)

Yes in case of a *currentAccount* the computation of the interest is useless, but if you want to avoid that you have to double the memberships classes, the directed association to a membership is not on *userAccount* but each sub class, and the operations *getWithdrawLimit* and *getTransfertLimit* are abstract in *userAccount*. This is more complicated and I don't think it's worth the effort

Comment: Thanks man. Very well explained. Your help is much appreciated! :)